# WPF Graph change when calendar date changes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have made a WPF graph that pulls data from a database. I need the data to automatically change on date change.

Here is my code:

XAML Code:

```
    <DVC:Chart Name="callLogs" 
       Background="SteelBlue"
       Margin="136,0,0,0"
               Title="Calls Per Hour"
               BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <DVC:Chart.Axes>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Ammount of calls" ShowGridLines="True"/>
        </DVC:Chart.Axes>
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Calls per Hour" 
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            </DVC:ColumnSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
    <DatePicker x:Name="Datepicker1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="10,21,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="126" 
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
```

C# code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Xml;


 using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;
 using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
 using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

 namespace MainWindow
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadColumnChartData();
    }

    private void LoadColumnChartData()
    {
        Datepicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        string pickDate = Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        int[] callCounter = new int[100];
        int[] callHour = new int[100];
        int counter = 0;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=nl-reportserver;Database=RealConnect;User Id=sa;Password=<password>");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pickDate", pickDate);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RC_callsperhour where convert(date,call_logdate,120) = convert(date,@pickDate,120) order by callhour";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                callHour[counter] = reader.GetInt32(2);
                callCounter[counter] = reader.GetInt32(3);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();

        sqlConnection1.Close();

        ((ColumnSeries)callLogs.Series[0]).ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, counter).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(callHour[i], callCounter[i])).ToArray();

    }
}
}
```

Please note that I have removed the password from the sql connection for security purposes.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF binding for getting data. First you need create a `ObservableCollection<YourDataModel>` then date changed it will set the your model class property:

```
public class YourDataModel
{
    public property int CallHour { get;set; }
    public property int CallCounter { get;set; }

    public YourDataModel(callHour int, callCounter int)
    {
       CallHour = callHour;
       CallCounter = callCounter;
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<YourDataModel> dataModel; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataModel = new ObservableCollection<YourDataModel>();

        //set itemsource property or you can bind from XAML
        //which is name columnseries x:Name=CallsPerHour
        CallsPerHour.ItemsSource = dataModel;
    }

    //when date change running this function
    private void GettingDataFromSql()
    {
        ...
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            YourDataModel data = new YourDataModel( reader.GetInt32(2), 
            reader.GetInt32(3));
            dataModel.Add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DVC:Chart.Series>
    <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Calls per Hour" 
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding CallHour, Mode=OneWay}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding CallCounter, Mode=OneWay}">
    </DVC:ColumnSeries>
</DVC:Chart.Series>
```